# How to make a column of a table to take only two words per line in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a table in html which is updated when a person chosse an item from the item list. I want when a cell of the table is updated, it should only take two words of the selected item and if the selected item is of three words, then the third word should print on next line of the cell.

**This is html table from where an item is selected**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;"><input type='checkbox' name='it's 2' value='Two Words'>Two words</input>
      </td>
      <td style="width:200px;"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;">
          <input type='checkbox' name='this is three' value='Three Words' >Three words Next line</input>
      </td>
      <td style="width:200px;"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**This is the html table which is updated...**

```
<table border="1" class="table2">
   <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Value</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="text"></td>
      <td class="value"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I want that second element of first table when selected is printed on second table but in two lines, where first line will have "three words" and the second line will have "Next line" on the same cell of second table. Pl help.

jQuery Code :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        var x = $(this).val();
        $('.text').append(x + ' <br />').show();
        var z = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.value').append(z + ' <br />');
    }
    else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){ 
        var x = $(this).val();
        var y = $('.text').text().replace(x, '');
        $('.text').text(y).show();
        $('.text').append('<br/>');
        var z = $(this).attr('name');
        var a = $('.value').text().replace(z, '');
        $('.value').text(a).show();
        $('.value').append(' <br/>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Share what you've tried or setup a jsfiddle

Comment: I have tried but my logic is not fitting to my code.. pl help.

Answer (score 0):

To capture first two words: `var theTwoWords = yourText.match(/([a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+)/)[0];` To get the next two after these: `var theNextTwoWords = theTwoWords.substr(theTwoWords.length + 1);`